# Azure Functions: Application freezes - "UnableToLoadExpressionAssembly" in error message

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have an Azure Functions application which once in a while "freezes" and stops processing messages and timed events.

When this happens I do not see much in the logs (AppInsight), except for the following error message telling me "UnableToLoadExpressionAssembly":

```
timestamp [UTC]: 2018-02-13T09:18:19.609Z
message: UnableToLoadExpressionAssembly
severityLevel: 3
customDimensions:
    LogLevel: Error
    prop__{OriginalFormat}: UnableToLoadExpressionAssembly
    Category: Host.Startup
client_Type: PC
client_IP: 0.0.0.0
cloud_RoleName: (...)
cloud_RoleInstance: (...)
appId: (...)
appName: (...)
iKey: (...)
sdkVersion: azurefunctions: 1.0.11510.0
itemId: e5362c17-109e-11e8-93fc-0f54eb87135a
itemType: trace
itemCount: 1
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can share? Also, if you could share your function app information as described here, it might help find additional information about what is going on: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: No stack trace since there are no exceptions registered in AppInsights. This error message is found in traces there. It _could_ be that the freezing problem (no messages/timers processed) are unrelated to the mentioned error message.  I will send you app information in an email.

Comment: Took a closer look at your sites and looks like some of them are not properly synchronized for activation. How are you deploying your files?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have now converted to zip deployment. Within a day or so I will know wether it is the solution. More information: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

Comment: Which mechanism were you using?

Comment: Seems like the tool was doing file copying to wwwroot. Not good. Should we do zip-based deployment for regular web applications as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the deployment mechanism used not initiating a trigger synchronization, which prevents the infrastructure from activating the Function App when needed.

Deployments using the CI/CD integration, Visual Studio, MSDeploy or ZIP deploy will trigger that synchronization and ensure your function app is activated when needed.

Comment: A week on vacation, and the site is still running fine.

Comment: It seems like I was too quick. Production app works fine, the others do not. I have posted a new and more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009111/azure-functions-application-freezes-without-any-error-message