# Azure Functions: Application freezes - without any error message

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions application which once in a while "freezes" and stops processing messages and timed events.

When this happens I do not see anything in the logs (AppInsight), neither exceptions nor any kind of unfamiliar traces.

The application has following functions:

- One processing messages from a Service Bus topic subscription (belonging to another application)
- One processing from an internal storage queue
- One timer based function triggered every half hour
- Four HTTP endpoints

Our production app runs fine. This is due to an internal dashboard (on big screen in the office), which polls one of the HTTP endpoints every 5 minutes, there by keeping it alive.

Our test, stage and preproduction apps stop after a while, stopping to process messages and timer events.

This question is more or less the same as my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763889) question, but the without error message that was in focus then. Much fewer error messages now, as our deployment has been fixed.

Comment: If someone from the Azure Functions team is listening: Fabio knows which sites this is about.

Comment: What's your App Service Plan?

Comment: We are using a consumption plan!

Comment: Please [share your app name](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately) and an example UTC time at which the timer function should have run and didn't.

Comment: I have tried to send an email. Not sure about the email address, though. Please contact me directly if not received.

Comment: As requested: 
2018-02-27T20:54:47.450 [Info] Function started (Id=df32c224-3826-489c-893e-8a08c9b39105)

Comment: Example UTC time which it should have run: 2018-02-27T20:30

Comment: Kindly provide the region that the Function execution with ID=df32c224-*

Comment: This is hosted in west-europe.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. I am moving this thread to our GitHub repo for better tracking. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2474 Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more detailed analysis can be found in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2474).

On a consumption plan, all triggers are registered in the host, so that these can be handled, leading to my functions being called at the right time. This part of the host also handles scalability.

I had two bugs:

1. Wrong deployment. Do zip based deployment as [described in the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push).
2. Malformed `host.json`. Comments in JSON are not right, although it does work in *most* circumstances in Azure Functions. But not all.

The sites now works as expected, both concerning availability and scalability.

Thanks to the people in the Azure Functions team (Ling Toh, Fabio Cavalcante, David Ebbo) for helping me out with this.